# Designated action to a column in DataGridview C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

[image]

this code for add the column 'Check-Out' and make all the Values in Color Green:

```
DataGridViewButtonColumn column = new DataGridViewButtonColumn
{
    FlatStyle = FlatStyle.System;
    DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.ForestGreen;
    HeaderText = "Check-Out";
    Text = "Check-Out";
    UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
};

dataGridView1.Columns.Add(column);
```

I want select for example for id=1, the field 'Check-Out'
... to change the Green 'Check-Out' to Red 'Check-Out'

I have try with this code (but for all fields...):

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    string col1 = dr.Cells["Check-Out"].ToString();

    dr.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red;
}
```

I have an error: *"The column called Check-Out is not found"* !!!

Thanks

Comment: Why do you get the string col1 in the 1st place?? You set the whole row to red anyway. This will win over the green columns. To override both you can set any cell's Style.BackColor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to give your column a name:

```
DataGridViewButtonColumn column = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
column.Name = "Check-Out";
```

Comment: thanks, do that
the Error disappeared,
But the field Green ...not chage to RED...
How modifie my code?

Answer (score 0):

i find the solution

this is the code:

```
  private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        int col = this.dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
        int row = this.dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;

        dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.Red;
    }
```

thanks for you all